# Virtual desktops with custom taskbar pinned applications

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, virtual-desktop, pinning

Is there a windows 7 application that enables to pin different taskbar applications by virtual desktop?

Comment: What application are you using to create virtual desktops?

Comment: dexpot, but I'm open to changes

Comment: I've been reading multiple questions here at SU about virtual desktop solutions for Windows, but none seem to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [SysInternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx)

Comment: at first view it seems to work, but after having removed some pinned apps and tried them on original desktop they disappear

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Windows Pager](http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/) , it creates multiple Desktop instances so it should have what you desire.